# Hyperref does not work for legend labels inside \subbottom

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, hyperref, cross-referencing, memoir

When I use `Hyperref` package together with memoir class, and when I put a label to a `PGFPlot` inside a `subbottom` environment, and try to reference to it, an error reported:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \Hy@setref@link.
```

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper, oneside, article]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}
A test for hyperref, subbottom of memoir class, and legend reference.
This is the legend reference:\ref{plot:firstplot}.

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\subbottom[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot coordinates {(0,0)(0.5,1)(1,2)};
  \label{plot:firstplot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If we do not use `Hyperref`, or if we do not put the plot inside `subbottom`, things would work out well.

Answer (score 6):

I can reproduce the issue.

The cause is that both memoir and pgfplots override `\label` (in an incompatible way). Pgfplots has some workaround to restore its own `\label` locally, but that work-around appears to conflict with some operation caused by hyperref.

A workaround is to load `hyperref` *before* `pgfplots`, in this case, everything works as expected.

I would prefer a better solution which works in all cases, but it may need a deep digging into the root cause (volunteers?).