# Is there a robust alternative to the undocumented `\pgfplotsplotfromname`

Tags: pgfplots, hyperref, tikz-external

The undocumented `\pgfplotsplotfromname` was useful in the solution of this warning:

[\ref{named pgfplot}, externalization and hyperref gives warning: name{pgfplotslink.0.0} has been referenced but does no t exist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383547/refnamed-pgfplot-externalization-and-hyperref-gives-warning-namepgfplotsli)

Its actually a workaround for the warnings that appear when using a named plot from `pgfplots` in combination with externalization and `hyperref.`

I am looking for a better solution.